# Change References indent on ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, memoir

How do I fix references indent on `ToC` ?

I know it's possible to use `tocloft` to adjust `\cftsetindents{section}` for sections etc, but what about references? I already tried `\cftchapterindent }{0em}` and didn't work for references.
I need the references to be indented as chapters, even though it's not numbered. See image at the end.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectlanguage{brazil}    
\usepackage[style=abnt-numeric,language=brazilian,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[]{sample.bib}    
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@book{ASM,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Bla bla 1}
\cite{ASM}
\chapter{Bla bla 3}
\chapter{Bla bla 3}    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: References with indent]

Comment: `memoir` emulates `tocloft` by default -- an undesirable feature of `memoir`, in my point of view

Comment: But if I define as a section, won't the header it self look like section? On my dissertation references must have chapter style (bold face, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `biblatex` manual explicitly states about the mischief in conjunction with `memoir` and recommends the `heading=...` and `\defbibheading`.

I used

```
\defbibheading{bay}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}
}
```

i.e. adding a `chapter` heading as usual and an empty `number` entry, i.e. the `\bibname` entry is indented like the other chapter entries.

Use `\printbibliography[heading=bay]` then.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectlanguage{brazil}    
\usepackage[style=numeric,language=brazilian,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[]{sample.bib}    
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@book{ASM,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Bla bla 1}
\cite{ASM}
\chapter{Bla bla 3}
\chapter{Bla bla 3}    
\defbibheading{bay}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}
}
\printbibliography[heading=bay]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks! I did read memoir manual, but i wasn't sure on how to use `defbibheading`. Other awnsers with this command weren't clear either, wish memoir had more examples.

Comment: @G.Bay I did not look into `memoir` manual -- but I remembered to have read about this in `biblatex` manual.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @ChristianHupfer is to be preferred as it is based on a reading of the `biblatex` manual ... here is a hack which is more cumbersome.

I have added `hyperref` only for testing compatibility.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectlanguage{brazil}    
%\usepackage[style=abnt-numeric,language=brazilian,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[language=brazilian,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[]{sample.bib}    
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@book{ASM,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  \newif\if@intoc

  \AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldbibname\bibname
  \renewcommand*{\bibname}{\tocbibname@prefix\oldbibname}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\tocbibname@prefix}
                        {\if@intoc\expandafter\chapternumberline\fi{}}%
  }

  \newenvironment{intoc}{\@intoctrue}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{intoc}
  \tableofcontents*
\end{intoc}
\chapter{Bla bla 1}
\cite{ASM}
\chapter{Bla bla 3}
\chapter{Bla bla 3}  

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]